# Como utilizar o Search Bar com a class pessoa - swift 3

Tags: classes, swift-3, uisearchbar

Bom dia..
Tenho a class pessoa

```
class pessoa
{
    var nome : String = “”;
    var idade : Int = 0;
    var foto  : UIImage!;    
}
extension pessoa
{
   class func Gerar_Registros(pQtd : Int) -> Array<pessoa>
   {
       var vpessoa : pessoa;
       for A in 1...pQtd
       {
          vpessoa = pessoa();
          vpessoa.nome = “Nome..: \(A)”;
          vpessoa.idade = A;
          vpessoa.foto =  UIImage(named : “foto1”);    
       }
   }
}
```

Normalmente para fazer o search bar funcionar utilizo essa variavel

> var Array_Nome = [“Maria”,”Jose”,”João”,”Antonio”],
>
> var Array_Busca : [String]!;

```
> Class vc_01 : UIViewController
>         {
>            var Array_Nome = [“Maria”,”Jose”,”João”,”Antonio”];
>            var Array_Busca : [String]!;
>            override func viewDidLoad()
>             {
>                 super.viewDidLoad()
>                 
>                 Array_Busca = Array_Nome;    
>             }    
> 
> func tableView(_ tableView : UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
> Numeros_Linhas_na_Secao : Int)-> Int // Esta Metodo faz parte do
> UITableViewDataSource
>     {
>         return self.Array_Busca.count;
>     }
>     
>     
>     
>     
>     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
>         
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cel01") as! cel01
>         
>         cell.ContactNameLabel.text! = Array_Busca[indexPath.row]
>         
>         cell.selectionStyle = .none
>         
>         return cell
>         
>     }
> 
>     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
>     {
>             Array_Busca = searchText.isEmpty ? Array_Nome : Array_Nome.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
>       
>             return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
>         }
>         
>         tableView.reloadData()
>     }
>     
>     func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
>         self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
>     }
>     
>     
>     func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
>         searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
>         searchBar.text = ""
>         searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
>     }
>         }
```

Já estou tentando a vários dias fazer o código acima rodar com a classe pessoa.
Alguém sabe como fazer ??? Poderia me dizer como??
Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos :)
Abraços :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente substituir a linha

```
return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
```

Por:

```
item.lowercased().range(of: searchText.lowercased()) != nil
```

Comment: Bom dia Felipe... Então... o ITEM original é uma STRING e o que eu gostaria de saber é como fazer o search com uma class... Como ficaria a linha: return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil .... Para a classe PESSOA?? O que eu teria que colocar no lugar do item??  Abraços e obrigado pela atenção :)